# Alternatives to Cassette?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, minify

Andrew Davey created a very [nice library](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette) to allow on the fly minification and concatenation of js/css files to ASP.NET MVC projects. However, I'm using WebForms with .NET 3.5 and I'm thinking about modifying it to fit my project. Before I do that, I would like to know if any of you guys know any alternatives that might fit WebForms with .NET 3.5 projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some similar projects:

- http://shinkansen.codeplex.com/
- http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/
- http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/

At least the first two should work with .NET 3.5

*Edit* - Even more similar projects:

- http://mscd.codeplex.com/
- http://chirpy.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt

Scott Guthrie's post about the new [bundling and minification support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx) which was [published with the MVC4 beta release](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt) in a Webforms project and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Cassette works fine with WebForms, it has no dependency on MVC.

As for .NET 3.5 it may be possible to back port it. It would be great if you want to give that a go! :)

Comment: I am trying it but I can't get past Isolated Storage... the GetLastWriteTime seems impossible to emulate in 3.5 :( See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180653/isolatedstoragefile-getlastwritetime-for-net-3-5

Answer (score 1):

We are using http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ and are very happy about it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into MVC4 / ASP.NET 4.5 **beta**  Bundles implementation - you might want to wait until it is released and use that functionality when released instead of switching to third parties right now.