# IsolatedStorageFile.GetLastWriteTime for .NET 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, isolatedstorage

I am trying to see if I can port a .NET 4 project (specifically, [Cassette](http://getcassette.net)) to 3.5.

I finished the entire main project but now I'm on the last error and I can't seem to figure out a workaround.

Cassette uses Isolated Storage to store asset files and in .NET 4 the related classes have been overhauled to be much more useful. In .NET 3.5, however, there are a lot of things missing.

I am stuck on getting the last write time of an isolated file. Is there a way to do this in 3.5 or is it a lost cause?

[MSDN for .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getlastwritetime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: @jacko, for Cassette they did not use LastFileWriteTime for isolated storage, it was only used on actual files. So in the end it simply throws a NotImplementedException.

Comment: In addition, I originally created a index file that would record write times for any file, then it would look it up when you asked. However, as I said above, overkill for Cassette specifically.

Comment: Example of above workaround (gotta love version control!): https://github.com/kamranayub/cassette/blob/78d2f8dd0ab623d29655037dd9d90660c538d12b/src/Cassette/IO/IsolatedStorageFile.cs

Comment: I meant, with the cassette 3.5 fork :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps scrap support for Isolated Storage in the .NET 3.5 version of Cassette? It's easy to use a regular file system directory (e.g. App_Data) instead.

Comment: So if I removed all the IsolatedStorage related classes/interfaces, that would be sufficient?

Comment: Follow-up: we found Cassette did not even need to use LastFileWriteTime so we simply threw a NotImplementedException. Example of index file workaround: https://github.com/kamranayub/cassette/blob/78d2f8dd0ab623d29655037dd9d90660c538d12b/src/Cassette/IO/IsolatedStorageFile.cs