# Bundling & Minification in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, bundling-and-minification

`ASP.NET 4.5` includes a new feature to minify and bundle CSS and JavaScript within your web application.

Is there anything similar to apply bundling and minification for CSS and JS files in `ASP.NET 3.5`(Web forms)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Cassette?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026029/alternatives-to-cassette)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no built in tool is available in 3.5

You can use [`YUICompressor`](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) and add those compressed version in your page

There is a [`YUICompressor for .Net`](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) is available