# having multiple js references in cshtml is slowing down the page?

Tags: javascript, razor

in my MVC view(cshtml),i created a different js file for different use, I just call them in cshtml,I thought its a good way to separate js logic from view,so in my view there are 10 js references for different purposes and use, I have read somewhere,this way of referencing, increases the number of trips to server, and slows down the page loading time, at the same time, if I want to write all the js in view, it becomes unreadable and messy, what should i do then?I'm new in all these, thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Read up on bundling and minification. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET 4.5 you can bundle all your css and javascript files.

This combines all your javascript files(also css) into on script file that is minified.

If you have 10 js files they can be optimized into one js file.This document explains it better [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Here is a basic example.

In the App_Start Folder, they is a BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)

{
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/HomePage/js").Include("~/Home/index.js", 
               "~/Home/loading.js")
            );
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

Make sure your webconfig has debug turn off turn it back on for production enviroment

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="false" />

</system.web>
```

Just add the following to your page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/HomePage/js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Comment: No it will not. Depending on what you are looking for I suggest your try the following online bundler: [jsCompressor](https://jscompress.com/) or read up on the solutions from these  threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123344/bundling-minification-in-asp-net-3-5

Comment: thanks,one more question,if i use js compressor,i should create another js file to put the compressed js inside?so,when i want to publish the site,how it will be realized to publish the compressed one or the main one?

Comment: You dont need to create another file, use the one from the jsCompressor, remove all references to the other js files.

For the dev environment you can use multiple js files on your page this will help you with debugging your work .

When you deploy for production compress all your js files into one and only use that minified one.It  will provide  performance for production

Comment: so,for the publish,i mix all the js i created in one,and compress it,and reference the project to it?

Comment: Yes just reference the minified  file on your project

Comment: please mark answer as right if it solved your problem